# spring boot application in docker terminates immediately

Tags: docker, spring-boot, dockerfile

Simple spring boot application trying to run in docker, however after docker run, exits immediately. Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:latest
VOLUME /tmp

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
ADD app.jar /opt/app/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/opt/app/app.jar"]
```

Docker run command

```
docker run -t -p 8080:8080 --name app -d app
```

In the container logs, the only output is the spring banner, and then the container terminates.

Am I missing something here.

Comment: post `docker events`

Comment: can you provide the full logs `docker container log <container-name>`?

Comment: Use `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --name app app` so that you see why it is dying. `-d` sends it to background

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any reason to use `anapsix/alpine-java:latest`

I recommand you to use the `openjdk:8-jre-alpine`, light weight and less in size comparitively.

create a war files instead of jar.

use the following

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ENV SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS \
    SLEEP_TIME=0 \
    JAVA_OPTS=""

# add directly the war
ADD *.war /app.war

EXPOSE 8080
CMD echo "The application will start in ${SLEEP_TIME}s..." && \
    sleep ${SLEEP_TIME} && \
    java ${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.war
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the reply. No issue with the Dockerfile, apparently my jar file has problem.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, can you let me know how you fixed this

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason container was failing to start was that the app couldn't connect to one of the external services and the reason I only saw Spring logo was that I had logback configured to work only under specific Spring profile and I overrode spring active profile with an environment variable but forgot to define that variable, so it was trying to start with an empty active profile.